# d3.js two concentric circles with bubbles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and have spent quite a time trying to figure this out but have failed. So, here I am asking for your help:

I need to make a bubble chart consisting of two concentric circles filled with bubbles. Let's say that the inner circle is filled with employers and the outer circle is filled with employees. And there should be a tiny spacing, like a margin, between the two circles.

Thank you in advance.

example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var diameter = 500,
        format = d3.format(",d"),
        color = d3.scale.category10();

        var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                    .sort(null)
                    .size([diameter, diameter])
                    .padding(3);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", diameter)
                    .attr("height", diameter)
                    .attr("class", "bubble");

        d3.json("flare2.json", function(error, root) {
            if (error) throw error;

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                        .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
                        .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

            node.append("title")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

            node.append("circle")
                        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
                        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

            node.append("text")
                        .attr("dy", ".3em")
                        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
        });

        // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
        function classes(root) {
            var classes = [];

            function recurse(name, node) {
                if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
                else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
            }

            recurse(null, root);
            return {children: classes};
        }

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

flare2.json

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "analytics",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "cluster",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Test1", "size": 1000},
                        {"name": "Test2", "size": 2000},
                        {"name": "Test3", "size": 3000},
                        {"name": "Test4", "size": 1000},
                        {"name": "Test5", "size": 2000},
                        {"name": "Test6", "size": 3000},
                        {"name": "Test7", "size": 1000}

                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "graph",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Test1", "size": 1000},
                        {"name": "Test2", "size": 2000},
                        {"name": "Test3", "size": 3000},
                        {"name": "Test4", "size": 1000},
                        {"name": "Test5", "size": 2000},
                        {"name": "Test6", "size": 3000},
                        {"name": "Test7", "size": 1000},
                        {"name": "Test8", "size": 2000},
                        {"name": "Test9", "size": 3000},
                        {"name": "Test10", "size": 1000},
                        {"name": "Test11", "size": 2000}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This code is made from other examples I found online so it's far from perfect and what I need. The two concentric circles need to be like on this [image](http://tutorial.webdesignershouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2-concentric-circles-centered.png) - yellow being the inner circle with employers and the blue being the outer circle with employees.

Comment: could you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code you tried to use?

Comment: You can grab it [here](http://moonlight.ba/demo/d3.zip)

Comment: please add code as a snippet or use something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I guess there won't be that many people on stackoverflow that are willing to download a zip file from an unknown url just to have a look on your code. Also please always add new information to the question and not in the comments.

Comment: I added the sample code.

Comment: @tufahija in this you wrote about employers and employees but i don't see any data set for it. Kindly add taht too